# Data Warehouse schema : Star or Snowflake (case included)

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, ssms, star-schema, snowflake-schema

I need a hand with a specific case for creating Data Warehouse schema for University.
I've tried to create a
 [schema] https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAtZM.jpg but it looks like im going in wrong direction

Case:

> University currently has 5 courses – Foundation, Business Computing,
>   Business, Economics, and Law. It provides education on 5 levels.  Each
>   academic year consist of 2 semesters. We have a number of modules that
>   belong to courses and some of them are core modules and some are
>   optional. Some modules are semester long and some are a year-long.
>   Each module has assessment components that have weights contributed to
>   the overall mark on the module. Assessments are of different types
>   like in-class test, coursework, final exam, etc. Students register on
>   courses starting from Foundation. Students might change the course
>   over time (e.g. transfer from Business to Business Computing).
>   University would like to know about: •    students registration on
>   courses and  modules and tracking changes to them over time.
>   • academic progress and performance of students  and faculty in
>   different courses and modules including assessment components
>   (coursework, in-class test, final exam, etc.).

If possible, please attach schema as a screenshot or whatever. Im newbie to Data Warehouse stuff, so i dont know much about it and have no expirience in creating them.
I will be very grateful for any help that will somehow closer to solving the problem.
Sorry for my english.
Thank you, and have a nice day.

Comment: Is there a normalized database from which you are going to extract the data?

Comment: Dan Bracuk,there is No data currently for data warehouse, after the schema is ready, i need to fill in some data to test queries that case requires (i can also show query requirements if needed).

Comment: Looks like there is noone who can actually help, well, what a pitty, anyway thank you for those who replied to my question and tried to help. The question is still open, any suggestions would be  appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure it would be hybrid snowflake as you have two fact tables here and will have other several dimension tables connected around

Answer (score 1):

Some quick ref on the advantages of both types of schemas. 
http://www.diffen.com/difference/Snowflake_Schema_vs_Star_Schema

Comment: For our reporting servers we convert our raw ERP data into usable tables (ETL's) and then with COGNOS create a snowflake schema for reporting.  This gave us the most versatility as out business processes constantly changes over time, with reporting execution time being our biggest sacrifice for this flexibility. However due to the custom reporting tables we generate for the reporting system, proper indexing minimizes the prenatally that this process naturally creates.